# SAVE operation returning storage _id?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is there a `save` operation in mongoose.js or mongodb api, which returns the _id of stored entry?

In mongoose the following will save the Entry.

```
p.save(function (err) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  else console.log('saved');
  })
})
```

Likewise `db.collection.save(document)` will save document in mongodb api. But in both cases, you need to query db again for _id, which I want to avoid. As it seems ineffient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you instantiate an object in Mongoose, the object will have an `_id` already assigned (as it's assigned on the client by default).

So, if you just check:

```
console.log(p.id);
```

You'll see that it has a value before you call `save`.

And in the case of using the native driver for Node.JS, the document is returned in the `result` parameter with the `_id` set.

```
var collection = db.collection("tests");
collection.insert(p, function(err, results) {
   if (err) { return; }
   // results in an array, and in this case
   // results[0]._id would be available
});
```